# Refresh data on second click Ajax?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, leaflet

I using `Ajax` to send data to Flask form JavaScript and after click a button on the map is creating a marker and the data from `Ajax` are added in the marker popup. I create a `polyline` form `coordinates` and after click on the popup polyline is display on the map. The problem is when I click more click than once everything works fine because are different data but is a problem with `polyline`. When I add two markers and I click on first marker is display `polyline` for second one. I have two ideas how to do it but I don't know if It possible to do it like that.

1. Refresh page after second click and add marker again
2. Somehow add `polyline` to specific marker

Code in JavaScript:

```
$("#search-button_event").click(function () { // make ajax request on btn click
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/mapaa", // url to the function
            data: {
                nameevent: $("#name_of_event").val(), // value of the form
            },
            success: function (response) {
                 nazwa = (response['name']);
                 droga = (response['route']);
                 

                 droga_without = droga.replaceAll("{","")
                 droga_with2 = droga_without.replaceAll("}","")
                 var string = droga_with2.split(',');

                

                let marker_event = L.marker(array[0]).bindPopup()
                marker_event._popup.setContent(
                                                                '<form method="POST" action="/mapaa"'+
                                                                '<p>Nazwa: '+nazwa+'</p>'+
                                                                '<input name="nameOfEvent" type="hidden" value="' + nazwa + '" id="nameOF">' +
                                                                
                                                                '<button type="submit" id="form-submit" name="form-submit"  class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Dołącz do wydarzenia</button>'+
                                                                '</form>')

                marker_event.addTo(mymap)

                polyline_event = L.polyline(array,{color: 'red'})
                marker_event.on('click',function(){
                    polyline_event.addTo(mymap)
                })
                marker_event.getPopup().on('remove', function() {
                    polyline_event.remove()
                })

                mymap.setView(array[0],14)

            },
        });
    });
```

Comment: maybe you should keep markers (or popups) on the list - and maybe then markers (popups) will keep its settings. Or maybe you should keep polylines on list and assign different element from list to different popups. Or maybe it should assign as `on("click", function(polyline) {...})` and maybe this way it will send polyline as value (and it will duplicate it) and it will use different values for different clicks. It would need to keep `polylines` in different `scope`. Current code uses the same variable `polyline_event` in all functions (variable in the same `scope`) so they use the same values

Comment: this is problem only with JavaScript and it has nothing to do with python and flask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is `variable scope`. All `click` use the same variable `polyline` so all of them use the same value in this variable.

So you have problem like in this code - all popups display the same `"Popup 3"`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<h1>WRONG</h1>

<div id="popup_1">Click to show Popup 1</div></br>
<div id="popup_2">Click to show Popup 2</div></br>
<div id="popup_3">Click to show Popup 3</div></br>

<script language="javascript">

polyline = "Popup 1";

$('#popup_1').on('click', function(){
    alert(polyline);
});

polyline = "Popup 2";

$('#popup_2').on('click', function(){
    alert(polyline);
});

polyline = "Popup 3";

$('#popup_3').on('click', function(){
    alert(polyline);
});

</script>
```

If you put code in function and send `polyline` as value then it will assign to different local variables and they will work correctly. Is is `closure`.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<h1>GOOD</h1>

<div id="popup_1">Click to show Popup 1</div></br>
<div id="popup_2">Click to show Popup 2</div></br>
<div id="popup_3">Click to show Popup 3</div></br>

<script language="javascript">

function assign(item, line) {
    $(item).on('click', function(){
        alert(line);
    });
}    

polyline = "Popup 1";

assign('#popup_1', polyline);

polyline = "Popup 2";

assign('#popup_2', polyline);

polyline = "Popup 3";

assign('#popup_3', polyline);

</script>
```

---

**EDIT:**

Little different way. It uses function which gets `polyline` and returns new function with this value.

```
function assign(line) {
    return function(){
        alert(line);
    }
}    

polyline = "Popup 1";

$('#popup_1').on('click', assign(polyline));

polyline = "Popup 2";

$('#popup_2').on('click', assign(polyline));

polyline = "Popup 3";

$('#popup_3').on('click', assign(polyline));
```

---

**EDIT:**

Another version with anonymous function

```
polyline = "Popup 1";

(function() {
    let val = polyline;
    $('#popup_1').on('click', function(){
        alert(val);
    });
})()    

polyline = "Popup 2";

(function() {
    let val = polyline;
    $('#popup_2').on('click', function(){
        alert(val);
    });
})()    

polyline = "Popup 3";

(function() {
    let val = polyline;
    $('#popup_3').on('click', function(){
        alert(val);
    });
})()
```

---

**EDIT:**

It seems it works also without `function` but only with block `{..}` and `let` (can't be `var`). I tested only in newest Firefox and don't know if it will work in very old browser.

```
polyline = "Popup 1";

{
    let val = polyline;  // it has to use `let`, not `var`
    $('#popup_1').on('click', function(){
        alert(val);
    });
}

polyline = "Popup 2";

{
    let val = polyline;  // it has to use `let`, not `var`
    $('#popup_2').on('click', function(){
        alert(val);
    });
}

polyline = "Popup 3";

{
    let val = polyline;  // it has to use `let`, not `var`
    $('#popup_3').on('click', function(){
        alert(val);
    });
}
```

or shorter

```
{
    let polyline = "Popup 1";  // it has to use `let`, not `var`
    $('#popup_1').on('click', function(){
        alert(polyline);
    });
}

{
    let polyline = "Popup 2";  // it has to use `let`, not `var`
    $('#popup_2').on('click', function(){
        alert(polyline);
    });
}

{
    let polyline = "Popup 3";  // it has to use `let`, not `var`
    $('#popup_3').on('click', function(){
        alert(polyline);
    });
}
```

---

Full working code for test.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
<a href="/wrong">WRONG</a><br>
<a href="/good1">GOOD 1</a><br>
<a href="/good2">GOOD 2</a><br>
<a href="/good3">GOOD 3</a><br>
<a href="/good4">GOOD 4</a><br>
<a href="/good5">GOOD 5</a><br>
''')

@app.route('/good1')
def good1():
    return render_template_string('''
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<h1>GOOD 1</h1>

<div id="popup_1">Click to show Popup 1</div></br>
<div id="popup_2">Click to show Popup 2</div></br>
<div id="popup_3">Click to show Popup 3</div></br>

<script language="javascript">

function assign(item, line) {
    $(item).on('click', function(){
        alert(line);
    });
}    

polyline = "Popup 1";

assign('#popup_1', polyline);

polyline = "Popup 2";

assign('#popup_2', polyline);

polyline = "Popup 3";

assign('#popup_3', polyline);

</script>
''')

@app.route('/good2')
def good2():
    return render_template_string('''
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<h1>GOOD 2</h1>

<div id="popup_1">Click to show Popup 1</div></br>
<div id="popup_2">Click to show Popup 2</div></br>
<div id="popup_3">Click to show Popup 3</div></br>

<script language="javascript">

function assign(line) {
    return function(){
        alert(line);
    }
}    

polyline = "Popup 1";

$('#popup_1').on('click', assign(polyline));

polyline = "Popup 2";

$('#popup_2').on('click', assign(polyline));

polyline = "Popup 3";

$('#popup_3').on('click', assign(polyline));

</script>
''')

@app.route('/good3')
def good3():
    return render_template_string('''
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<h1>GOOD 3</h1>

<div id="popup_1">Click to show Popup 1</div></br>
<div id="popup_2">Click to show Popup 2</div></br>
<div id="popup_3">Click to show Popup 3</div></br>

<script language="javascript">

polyline = "Popup 1";

(function() {
    let val = polyline;
    $('#popup_1').on('click', function(){
        alert(val);
    });
})()    

polyline = "Popup 2";

(function() {
    let val = polyline;
    $('#popup_2').on('click', function(){
        alert(val);
    });
})()    

polyline = "Popup 3";

(function() {
    let val = polyline;
    $('#popup_3').on('click', function(){
        alert(val);
    });
})()    

</script>
''')

@app.route('/good4')
def good4():
    return render_template_string('''
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<h1>GOOD 4</h1>

<div id="popup_1">Click to show Popup 1</div></br>
<div id="popup_2">Click to show Popup 2</div></br>
<div id="popup_3">Click to show Popup 3</div></br>

<script language="javascript">

polyline = "Popup 1";

{
    let val = polyline;  // it has to use `let`, not `var`
    $('#popup_1').on('click', function(){
        alert(val);
    });
}

polyline = "Popup 2";

{
    let val = polyline;  // it has to use `let`, not `var`
    $('#popup_2').on('click', function(){
        alert(val);
    });
}

polyline = "Popup 3";

{
    let val = polyline;  // it has to use `let`, not `var`
    $('#popup_3').on('click', function(){
        alert(val);
    });
}

</script>
''')

@app.route('/good5')
def good5():
    return render_template_string('''
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<h1>GOOD 5</h1>

<div id="popup_1">Click to show Popup 1</div></br>
<div id="popup_2">Click to show Popup 2</div></br>
<div id="popup_3">Click to show Popup 3</div></br>

<script language="javascript">

{
    let polyline = "Popup 1";  // it has to use `let`, not `var`
    $('#popup_1').on('click', function(){
        alert(polyline);
    });
}

{
    let polyline = "Popup 2";  // it has to use `let`, not `var`
    $('#popup_2').on('click', function(){
        alert(polyline);
    });
}



{
    let polyline = "Popup 3";  // it has to use `let`, not `var`
    $('#popup_3').on('click', function(){
        alert(polyline);
    });
}

</script>
''')


@app.route('/wrong')
def wrong():
    return render_template_string('''
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<h1>WRONG</h1>

<div id="popup_1">Click to show Popup 1</div></br>
<div id="popup_2">Click to show Popup 2</div></br>
<div id="popup_3">Click to show Popup 3</div></br>

<script language="javascript">

polyline = "Popup 1";

$('#popup_1').on('click', function(){
    alert(polyline);
});

polyline = "Popup 2";

$('#popup_2').on('click', function(){
    alert(polyline);
});

polyline = "Popup 3";

$('#popup_3').on('click', function(){
    alert(polyline);
});

</script>
''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True 
    app.run()
```

Comment: Yes you are right, I thought that exists other way.I change it like this way , thank you !

Comment: I added second method - it still need code in function but without `onclick` so this method can be used in other situations.

Comment: I added third method - with anonymous functions - but it seems less readable.

Comment: it seems it works also without anonymous function but only with block `{...}` and `let`. I added another example.

Comment: I used your second method and it works but thank you for others too !